# How to convert Apple Music M4P to MP3?

Tags: music, file-conversion, mp3

Is there any way to convert Apple Music M4P files to MP3?

iTunes doesn't allow to burn discs with Apple Music files, is there any other method?

Comment: -1 This looks like a scheme to steal music. Is there a practical problem you are seeking to overcome? What's the real end goal? (forgive me if my imagination isn't big enough to see past looking to strip DRM from music files)

Comment: The purpose is private use. For example I want to listen to my music in the car, which supports only MP3.

Comment: One legitimate use might be if you have a car with an SD slot for music to be played while people are in the car.  In that case the copyright owner could be OK with a lossy copy.

Answer (score 3):

M4P files are protected with Apple's Digital Rights Management (DRM) to stop conversion etc. Any unprotected MPEG4 files like .m4a can be converted easily with iTunes or various other applications but the DRM prevents this.

If you've purchased the music yourself, then upgrading to [iTunes Match](http://www.apple.com/itunes/itunes-match/) will let you replace the DRM protected files with standard m4a which Apple now uses for iTunes purchases. It's an annual subscription but you might also find it useful for syncing and updating other music in your library.

Also bear in mind that any conversion from m4a to mp3 will be from one lossy format to another, so you might notice a reduction in sound quality.

Comment: Thanks for iTunes Match hint, but Apple Music also does unpleasant magic things like hiding your previous purchases, so that's why not sure it will unveil Apple Music songs added to the library.

Comment: Apple Music and iTunes Match are separate services - you can use iTunes Match without signing up to Apple Music (has been around for a couple of years prior to the new service).

Comment: We tried the iTunes match link; it took us to a page http://www.apple.com/itunes/ on which the word match did not appear.  Another change in Apple's offering?